# Oracle sql developer can acess from loalhost but not ip address

Tags: oracle

**Here i have installed**

```
widows server 2008 64
orale 11g r2 64
```

now i want to access this from the ip address that i have set to my server not 
working i can't access trough the ip address....

when i use on my application .....local host it can get connected but 
when i add the ip for example 10.0.0.2 it's not connecting

now simply also on local when i write the ip address it's not connecting 
but with localhost works fine.....

so even i have used listener.
after running

```
C:\>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 10-NOV-2013 02:28
:36

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                10-NOV-2013 02:18:36
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 10 min. 2 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\a
dmin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         c:\app\administrator\diag\tnslsnr\WIN-3ALDRUD96NE\list
ener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pat_live" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "patlive", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pat_test" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "pattest", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "patliveXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "patlive", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pattestXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "pattest", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

C:\>
```

regards

Comment: Is your fire-wall open?

Comment: Your question is not very easy to understand. Are you trying to connect via the IP, when running your application on the same machine that the Oracle server is running on? Or are you trying to connect from a different machine? You should make it clear which one you are trying to do.

Comment: Your comments are hard to read because you are not writing proper sentences with punctuation.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, this happens when your hostname settings are detected incorrectly. Log in to the server where the database runs, and run:

```
lsnrctl status
```

You will most likely see that the listener listens on localhost/127.0.0.1, and not on the address which is reachable from the network.

Locate the listener.ora file (the lsnrctl status command displays the full path to it), edit it, e.g:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.0.2)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Then restart the listener.

```
lsnrctl stop
lsnrctl start
```

Or use the "Services" management console in Windows to restart the listener service.

Comment: Can you post the output of "lsnrctl status"?

Comment: i did on my question.

Comment: Ok, based on output, the listener is still listening on 127.0.0.1 instead of the externally reachable IP address. What is in this file: "C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora" ?

Comment: LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\log

Comment: As I said earlier, you have to replace (HOST = localhost) with the actual address you want the listener listen on, for example: (HOST = 10.0.0.2). After that, restart the listener, and verify with "lsnrctl status" that it is listening on 10.0.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Context:

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0

Steps:

1. **lsnrctl stop**
2. Change listener host from localhost to specific server IP
   Sample path: C:\app\root\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
3. **lsnrctl start**
4. for check: **lsnrctl status**

Answer (score -1):

Check that the IP address and port of the server machine is correct and that you can ping it from the other machine. If it is correct and you can ping it, you need to reconfigure the firewall that is preventing you connecting on that port. It could be a firewall on the server itself, or somewhere else on your network.

Comment: i have stop the filewall, even inside the same machine i installed the oracle now with the sqldeveloper if in host name i write localhost i can get to it but if i write the ip of same machine can get the ip has been set static..... still can get to sqldeveloper in same machine with the ip

Comment: Dear, i am not from USA, my native language is not English so, if you know persian i could make you understand... tahnks